# How can I print unique completed percentage?

Tags: java, list, jsp, set

For a project I am generating process log, which is displaying current completed percentage, but the problem is, It is showing same percentage may time for every percent. I want something that print every percentage value only once.

```
public class Progress {
    public static void progressPercentage(int done, int total) {        
        System.out.println();
        String iconLeftBoundary = "[";
        String iconDone = "*";
        String iconRemain = " ";
        String iconRightBoundary = "]";

        if (done > total) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int donePercents =  ((100 * done) / total) +1;

        StringBuilder bar = new StringBuilder(iconLeftBoundary);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (i < donePercents)
                bar.append( iconDone );
            else
                bar.append( iconRemain );
        }
        bar.append(iconRightBoundary);
        System.out.print("\r" + bar + " " + donePercents + "%");

        if (done == total) {
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Here method accepts to parameters one is done, and second is total. I am calculating % from these two parameters.

```
Output I am getting:
[*] 1%
[*] 1%
[*] 1%
[*] 1%
[*] 1%
[**] 2%
[**] 2%
[**] 2%
[**] 2%
[**] 2%

Expecting:
[*] 1%
[**] 2%
[***] 3%
[****] 4%
[*****] 5%
```

Comment: What about adding a condition that checks the current percentage is different from the last displayed ?

Comment: Make the method instance, not static, and use an instance variable to store the previous percentage you had.

Comment: Can you please give me a example?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a condition in begining of the method which check if done is  one of exactly point of the percentages or not.

```
if(done % (total / 100) != 0){
       return;
}
```